# Missing file in package from Maven's repo

Tags: java, configuration, maven

Currently, I'm trying to use Jazzy spell checking library in my project. However, I stumble on some strange exception. In short, it became clear, that Jazzy package in Maven repo was stripped of properties file, <s>which may be unnecessary (looks like, library works even without it</s>), but while using the program, it leaves exception messages in the console.

So, is there easy way to copy *.properties file into exact place in *.jar with Maven or what are the best approaches to deal with it?

**[edit]**
Without this file, library will not offer suggestions and will only indicate words, which are not in dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a theory: Jazzy stores property files along with java source files ([Example](http://jazzy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jazzy/jazzy/src/com/swabunga/spell/engine/configuration.properties?view=log)). That's not the way Maven handles stuff. Maven considers such resources to be under `src/main/resources`.

So I guess whoever did the Maven port forgot to add the src/main/java folder as resource folder (which you need to do if you keep resources along the java files):

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <!-- or whatever the source dir is called -->
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <!-- also add src/main/resources if you need it -->
</resources>
```

So I guess your best bet is to file a bug and ask for them to include this config.

Answer (score 1):

> So, is there easy way to copy *.properties file into exact place in *.jar with Maven or what are the best approaches to deal with it?

Remember that JAR files are just ZIP archives with a different extension. You can "unzip" the JAR and add whatever files you want programatically, like a properties file, if you want. You then just need to zip it all back up again and the JAR should work as expected.

The tricky thing about this solution is that you are using Maven for dependency management which will make it tricky or difficult to manipulate the JAR for your project. Ant would have been you friend in this case.

Either way, I don't think that is the best solution anyway. Plus I don't like criticizing Maven. ;)

I think the right thing to do is add your own version of the `whatever.properties` file in your own project. If you put in in your `src/main/resources` folder under the exact same package structure as the Jazzy library is expecting, it should find it properly at runtime.

So if Jazzy keeps the properties file in the `com.jazzy.props` package, place the file in your own project like this...

```
<project.root>/src/main/resources/com/jazzy/props/whatever.properties
```

I didn't actually try this but it should work in theory. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If a logger is involved you could just disable that logger.

Comment: I would like to fix the problem, not to ignore it

Comment: If you really want to solve this: Jazzy is Open Source, right? File an issue/ provide a patch/ talk to the developers.

Comment: @Puce It's not Jazzy issue, it's the issue of the package, which was pushed to the Maven repository.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But most likely the Jazzy team made that jar and deployed it to Maven Central. So the packaging should be fixed.

Comment: @Puce Probably, I'll send a message to the package maintainer, but it'll take some time to be fixed, so I need some solution/workaround right now :-/

Comment: It might be easier to download the source and fix the packaging yourself than manipulating the existing jar. Then use your fixed jar instead of the one from Maven Central. Afterwards you can use a diff tool to provide your patch back to the Jazzy community.

Answer (score 0):

Since jazzy is open source, it was forked and included with RText, which is another open source project.  I happened to have a need for RText (which builds with Ant) for use in another open source maven project (SQuirrel SQL Client), so I applied to Sonatype for permission to use the net.sf.jazzy groupId.  Since the release that comes with RText has bug-fixes and other mods, we chose to use a "special" versionId (0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1) that would (hopefully) indicate that this version was not an "official" jazzy release of version 0.5.2, but rather one that was shipped with RText version 1.4.1.  Unfortunately, I omitted the resources (config and translation property files) when I prepared the initial release.  I have corrected that by issuing another release which is available here: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jazzy/jazzy/0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1-2/.